# Microsoft Office Document Imaging with Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, ocr

Can I use the [MODI library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/about-microsoft-office-document-imaging-HP001077103.aspx) with Windows CE 6.0? Otherwise what kind of OCR can i use with Windows CE 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

MODI is not supported on Windows CE. [Nuance](http://nuance.com/) used to have a product called "Mobile OCR" that supported CE.  I don't see it on their web site any longer, though the [OmniPage Capture SDK](http://nuance.com/for-business/by-product/omnipage/csdk/index.htm) looks like it's the likely replacement.  Their site is unclear about platform support - they simply say "mobile" and "embedded" are supported, so you'd probably want to contact them and ask.